# Take stuff off end of char* array in C

Tags: c, char

How do I remove chars from the end of a char*? I have:
"123456ABC" and I want: "123456". Thanks!

Comment: Char? Char pointer? Char array? Char pointer array? Hmmm.

Answer (score 6):

You could set one of the elements to the null character. Say you wanted to cut a string "123456ABC" down to "123456", you could just do,

```
str[6] = '\0';
```

BUT the rest of the string will still have memory allocated for it. What you probably want to do is make a new string and copy the desired portion of your old string over to it, and then delete the old string.

Comment: I'd like to point out that this will not work if `str` is a pointer to a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

Terminate char * string with '\0'.

```
char c[] = "123456ABC";
c[6] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the length of the desired remaining string, **length**, set **str[length]='\0'** and do:

```
// Assuming str was obtained through malloc/realloc functions.
str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(1+length));
```

This way you shorten the conceptual string and also the memory it uses, in case you want to optimise!

Edit: thanks to Jim Balter for raising issues with my original proposal!

Comment: You're assuming str was obtained from malloc (or realloc). Also, sizeof(char) is mandated to be == 1 and is not necessary. And you changed the meaning of length from length of string to amount allocated.

Comment: I'll give you the first one! While sizeof(char) is mandated, I believe from seeing other people's learning curves that this verbosity helps clarify concepts, but I see your point. And I called **length** in this case the amount of chars that the string would have **after** reduction...

Comment: after the realloc, `str[length]='\0'` is UB. And I prefer the more general `realloc(array, nelems * sizeof *array)`, which is independent of the type.

Comment: UB? Pardon my ignorance but what does that mean?

Comment: Undefined behavior. Again: you changed the meaning of `length` from the length of the *string* to the length of the *array*. Better would be `str = realloc(str, length+1);`.

Comment: Ah you're absolutely right. Was changing the semantics indeed. Thanks.

Comment: Not used to that use of **sizeof *array**, can really help if refactoring a lot of allocations with some sort of regexp script :)